# Read only first few rows or header in sqlContext

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As mentioned https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv, 
I am also reading csv

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('cars.csv')
```

Is there any option to read only the header or only first few rows.
Basically I just want to check if a particular column is present in the dataframe or not?

Comment: When we load the dataframe from the csv ie the step:
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('cars.csv')

Will it load the entire data into memory?

Answer (score 0):

If the header option is set to true then you can use:

df.first()

In this way it will return the header line.